# Does CPU utilization refers also to time of handling system calls?

Tags: cpu, process, cpu-usage

Assume I want to calculate the CPU utilization of a process, which reads and write to a file.

In order to read and write, the process must use system calls. This means there will be time when the process will be idle, but the CPU will run OS commands (in kernel mode).

Do we consider this time as part of the time the process ran on the CPU, or does the CPU utilization of this process ignores this part? I am asking this because I know context switching isn't considered part of the calculation of CPU utilization.

Comment: On Linux/Unix, this is split between user (application) and system (kernel) time.

Comment: What operating system?